# Dnsmasq Configuration for OpenVPN

Tags: debian, vps, openvpn, dnsmasq

I'm trying to configure an OpenVZ VPS running Debian 6 to run OpenVPN. I've got OpenVPN running, and I can connect to it, but my traffic isn't passing through yet. I get an error when dnsmasq start, and I'm not sure how to resolve it. Here's the error that I get.

```
dnsmasq: failed to bind listening socket for 10.8.0.1: Address already in use failed!
```

Here's the output of netstat -ap.

```
user@lenwood:/usr# netstat -ap
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 *:microsoft-ds          *:*                     LISTEN      1341/smbd       
tcp        0      0 localhost:submission    *:*                     LISTEN      1459/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 *:netbios-ssn           *:*                     LISTEN      1341/smbd       
tcp        0      0 *:www                   *:*                     LISTEN      1401/apache2    
tcp        0      0 10.8.0.1:domain         *:*                     LISTEN      1381/named      
tcp        0      0 lenwood.com:domain       *:*                     LISTEN      1381/named      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.2:domain        *:*                     LISTEN      1381/named      
tcp        0      0 localhost:domain        *:*                     LISTEN      1381/named      
tcp        0      0 *:ssh                   *:*                     LISTEN      1476/sshd       
tcp        0      0 localhost:smtp          *:*                     LISTEN      1459/sendmail: MTA:
tcp        0      0 localhost:953           *:*                     LISTEN      1381/named      
tcp        0    240 lenwood.com:ssh          cpe-64-68-125-178:54763 ESTABLISHED 5316/0          
tcp6       0      0 [::]:domain             [::]:*                  LISTEN      1381/named      
tcp6       0      0 [::]:ssh                [::]:*                  LISTEN      1476/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 localhost:953           [::]:*                  LISTEN      1381/named      
udp        0      0 10.8.0.1:domain         *:*                                 1381/named      
udp        0      0 lenwood.com:domain       *:*                                 1381/named      
udp        0      0 127.0.0.2:domain        *:*                                 1381/named      
udp        0      0 localhost:domain        *:*                                 1381/named      
udp        0      0 lenwood.com:netbios-ns   *:*                                 1337/nmbd       
udp        0      0 lenwood.com:netbios-ns   *:*                                 1337/nmbd       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.2:netbios-ns    *:*                                 1337/nmbd       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.2:netbios-ns    *:*                                 1337/nmbd       
udp        0      0 *:netbios-ns            *:*                                 1337/nmbd       
udp        0      0 lenwood.com:netbios-dgm  *:*                                 1337/nmbd       
udp        0      0 lenwood.com:netbios-dgm  *:*                                 1337/nmbd       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.2:netbios-dgm   *:*                                 1337/nmbd       
udp        0      0 127.0.0.2:netbios-dgm   *:*                                 1337/nmbd       
udp        0      0 *:netbios-dgm           *:*                                 1337/nmbd       
udp        0      0 *:openvpn               *:*                                 3369/openvpn    
udp6       0      0 [::]:domain             [::]:*                              1381/named      
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1408905812 1361/saslauthd      /var/run/saslauthd/mux
unix  6      [ ]         DGRAM                    1408905918 1369/syslogd        /dev/log
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     1408907150 1459/sendmail: MTA: /var/run/sendmail/mta/smcontrol
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1436674630 5316/0              
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1408908858 1488/xinetd         
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1408907081 1459/sendmail: MTA: 
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1408906063 1381/named
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "traffic isn't passing through yet"? Can you ping 10.8.0.1 from a connected VPN client? If not it's probably a firewall issue. Posting the output of `iptables -nvL` would help to debug that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tcp        0      0 10.8.0.1:domain         *:*                     LISTEN      1381/named
```

It looks like bind is listening on that socket, which is why dnsmasq can't start. You need to configure bind to only listen on specific IP addresses, with something like the following in `named.conf`:

```
listen-on { 50.56.53.125; };
```

Comment: This solved it. Thank you! I set the listen-on option to listen to the external IP address, now everything works. Is it any kind of security risk for BIND to be listening to an external IP address?

Comment: BIND was listening on all addresses before, so it's more restrictive. Unless you don't want BIND to be externally accessible (i.e. you're only using it internally) you need it to listen on the external IP.

Answer (score 0):

What's the network scheme and configs?

If traffic won't route via tunnel, you surely won't get DNS answers (or whatever traffic you need).